# How to replace existing branch on SVN?

Tags: svn

I'm working on a project which latest code isn't on SVN. But on SVN, it do have an old copy of the same code which was written by another developer. When I started to work on to the same project, I was given the code which is on SVN (via AirDrop). Then I was updating the same code which is on my desktop (and not on SVN). I never commit anything on SVN.

Now my boss want me to put the latest (on which I have been worked) code on SVN.

He don't want to create an another branch for the same code. So he asked me to update the code on SVN. How should I do that? What's the proper way to get this done?

- I have checkout the code from SVN.
- I do have latest code for the same on my desktop.

I want to keep latest code on SVN (which is with me now).

What should I do?

Comment: You can update the checked-out code with the latest code (by replacing and/or svn adding and/or svn removing, depending on your modifications), then simply commit. Did you try it ?

Comment: I am only able to do is override the existing code, because the old and new has a lot difference. I don't know how to do that? What I think of is to replace the project folder.

Comment: You can do as you want to override the existing code in the working copy, but I think you should follow 2 rules: 1) always use "svn delete", "svn move", "svn rename"  (or TortoiseSVN) commands to delete, move and/or rename files or folders. And never use simple Windows commands. 2) use "svn add" (or TortoiseSVN) to link new folders or files to repository before commit.